# How can I fix a hood which doesn’t close tightly?

Tags: hood

Coming with an odd one here - my sister’s Yaris was bumped up in the front while parked. After a shop did the repair, the hood closes just fine without slamming it too hard but the actual hood doesn’t sit flush. It sits higher up. The rubber mounts on It don’t touch the crossmember, at least a finger away. I can push the hood and it goes into the correct position but once I let it go, it goes back to being too high. As it has no other contact, my suspect is the hood latch mechanism.

Looking at the bolts, it is in the highest position right now. Would lowering the latch pull the bonnet down and make the actual gap as it should? If not, what else can I do to adjust before just buying the crossmemvber and latch assembly and change them?

Comment: Perhaps the panel the latch is mounted on is too high, at least, I would check that...

Comment: I'd take it back, the shop didn't do the job right.

Comment: Either the latch needs adjusting, or something (the front structure of the car or the hood itself) was bent in the collision and needs either straightening or replacing - neither of which is cheap, compared with a hood that doesn't quite fit right.

Comment: The part the latch is mounted on is straight, already measured that. I was able to lower the latch slightly and the hood fixed itself somewhat on the right side, but still is bulging on the left. Perhaps two people will be needed - one to push the latch while I tighten the bolts.